# react-native, Async storage, not able to store returned value in variable, but logging it correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, promise, asyncstorage

```
export const getAsyncStorageToken = async () => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY);
    return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

calling the above function and storing the returned value in a local variable, doesnt do anything, example below:

```
var token_from_Async = '';

function RandomScreen(props) {

getAsyncStorageToken().then((token) => {
console.log('getAsyncStorageToken ',token.data.access_token); // works fine and prints the token value
token_from_Async = token.data.access_token; //not sure it assigns the value 
console.log("token_from_Async first", token_from_Async); //prints this
 return token.data.access_token;
 });

console.log("token_from_Async second", token_from_Async); //DOESNT prints this
```

sometimes in other cases, i encounter promise rejections also as like this :

TypeError: _SaveApi.default.get is not a function. (In '_SaveApi.default.get("GetActiveEvents?eventID=" + eventId)', '_SaveApi.default.get' is undefined)

Comment: It seems like an issue of execution order.  You should be creating and setting `token_from_Async ` via `useState` rather than as a local variable.

Comment: I will check with that, can you also check the last part related to Promise Reject i just added, thanks